# In Android how do you create a button with a progress bar going around it as per Material IO Guidance

Tags: android, android-layout, material-components-android

I want to make a button which has an indeterminate progress bar around it's outside, [as we can see here](https://material.io/archive/guidelines/components/progress-activity.html#progress-activity-types-of-indicators).

[image: What I want]

Based upon the available widgets, I cannot see how to make a circular button with this progress bar on it's outside.

At this point, I have my floating action button:

```
 <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="?android:attr/actionModeWebSearchDrawable" />
```

[image]

With no progress bar!

[I found this example - but cannot get it to load correctly into my project.](https://androidrepo.com/repo/ckurtm-FabButton-android-button)

Is there a 'native' simple way to achieve this design?

### Update

Following help, now I have something like this:

[image]

Note the right hand is the suggested answer. Left hand is the style of button I am aiming for.

My code is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.google.android.material.progressindicator.CircularProgressIndicator
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:progress="50"
                app:indicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
                app:trackColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:trackThickness="2dp"
                />
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="?attr/colorSecondary"
                app:cardCornerRadius="24dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:src="?android:attr/actionModeWebSearchDrawable"/>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Basically the left hand button is slightly larger with slightly smaller search image -- how can I edge closer to this? I have tried playing but can't quite get the sizing right. I thought adding padding would help but doesn't seem to make a difference. I wonder if there is a way to combine your solution with my floating action button - to perhaps get the best of both worlds more easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of Floating button maybe you can try it this way with Frame Layout and CardView

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.progressindicator.CircularProgressIndicator
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:progress="50"
            app:indicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:trackColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:trackThickness="2dp"
            />
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardCornerRadius="25dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true">

        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:src="@drawable/app_top_logo"/>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Very helpful - getting closer. Please see my updated question for a bit more help is needed!

Comment: For image maybe you can try scale type attribute. Or for once try with different image

Comment: With tweaks and experimentation, I got it - thank you Vivek!